# How to create a private area in JS application?

Tags: javascript, html, private

I have created an HTML5/JS application. Now I am packing my application using node-webkit instance. I want to create a private or password protected area in my app, where the user can't enter or can't see my code.
My main concern is to protect my content and code from the end user after he/she installs the application.

Uglification just protects your code to some extent. I also want to protect my content(pdf, videos and other files) from the users to copy it to some other location.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: I get confused whenever I see private and JS in the same sentence.

Comment: You want the same user to be able to **run** your code, but not **read** it? In an interpreter-based language?

Comment: @Siguza Yes, I want to protect my code & content from the same user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I obfuscate(protect) JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscateprotect-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot do that. You might want to consider obfuscating your code by minifying, uglifying etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscateprotect-javascript